# MacBookPro A1278 WiFi refuses to turn back on after working for 10 min after restart

Tags: wifi, internet, software, repair

I recently repaired this laptop from dead state (water damage) and it works fine now, except for the WiFi, which has intermittent problems. When I restart the Mac the WiFi works fine -- it connects without any issue -- then works for 10 minutes and turns off. When I try to turn on it, it refuses to, leaving a blank WiFi symbol. Once it even said that the hardware wasn't installed so I tried deleting the network interfaces.plist file, again when restarting it just worked for a little while.

Also I realized once it turns off sometimes when I delete the service and add it again it turns on again but doesn't show any WiFi networks in the list, searches but without finding anything. I am not sure what the issue is, the airport driver is in place I checked, I believe it's a software issue possibly even if it says WiFi failed, then why does it work for a little while? I am hoping that anyone can help me with this issue I am new to Macs and I was really happy the laptop worked after 2 years of disuse.

Edit: the laptop begun to freeze and crash just now.

Comment: in your rescue from drowning, did you replace the wifi card ?

Comment: live action, patient in emergency, I love it

Comment: I don't exactly know what the damage was I believe it was damaged by liquid it was purchased two years ago on eBay  not by me, never activated I didn't replace the card, the card seems fine as the component  it's the Airport Extreme 6.3.6 (read from the info on laptop). Now again showing no hardware installed, If I restart with deleting the network interfaces.plist it'll probably work again and then stop and it's a circle. Would u say it's the card? In general, laptop is fine after cleaning with isorophyl. Except the power button doesn't work at all.

Comment: it does sound like the card. But try the Apple Hardware test to see what it says.

Comment: How to I do that? This is first time I use a mac

Comment: Hold the D key immediately after boot to enter AHT.
Run test. Test took ~ 4 minutes.
Click on link to start Recovery mode.

Comment: some more instructions here https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/326453/46541  BE AWARE replacing the WiFi card is difficult process.  To check if you qualify you need to be able to disassemble and fix your Toaster in 15 minutes (which is simple in comparison).

Comment: Okay let's see. I read it could be the ribbon cable, I am sure this laptop is very old, could that be the issue here? Since it did work for some time at times but just stops and fails

Comment: I took out the motherboard and cleaned it already don't think the process of replacing the card will suprise me, I'm a electronic engineer haha.

Comment: I just got an error
Apple.com/support -2002D

Comment: So the AHT might be broken, did you reinstall the OS X, haha funny on the EE... did not know...so you are a champ... and while at it reset the SMC and the PRAM, yes it could be the ribbon cable (contacts)

Comment: The laptop didn't come with a hard drive, I had the Mac os El Capitan newest one installed on a used harddrive I don't know if using another harddrive or another OS could help.  I won't be able to reset some things, as it requires the power button hold down - which is not working at all. The ribbon cable may have become less connective with time and that liquid damage, what bothers me is why does it work at times perfectly (after restart usually for 10-30 min) but stops. What's the AHT?

Comment: Just noting. The WiFi Airport is in the screen, it's the old one not the one located next to motherboard.

Comment: sorry..AHT is Apple Hardware Test, since you just disclosed to have El Capitan installed on non standard drive, sounds like you do not have the AHT installed. Power button not working ? how do you turn it on/off ..OK .let me find some AHT for your model so you can try to download while the WiFi is working..OK here you go the link to Download AHT make sure it is for your Model  https://github.com/upekkha/AppleHardwareTest  OUT of curiosity is the cooling fan working ?

Comment: I turn it on by plugging in the power, I put a little pressure on the cable that connects the screen 
(longer one next to the fan) somehow works . I can only install aht if my internet is working on the laptop I don't have access to the larger system at the moment. Another case scenario is it turned on and WiFi connected straight away but won't load sites as it's not secure. Each time different issue although sometimes works that's why it's really confusing.

Comment: What happened now is WiFi is working but only in browser, apple store or other applications can't connect. Does this all really seem a software issue now?

Comment: please clarify, what do you mean only in browser ?  Hold Option key and click on the WiFi icon and see what it says there.

Comment: The WiFi worked fine for the last hour, I downloaded another browser and updates, it disconnected I was able to turn it back on once, now turned off again and button to turn it on doesn't work, it's a sticky issue

Comment: You are doing just fine. There is nothing I can help you with, other than learning from you.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help I appreciate it. You highlighted some important things to look out for in my Mac. It seems to be working now pretty well. :) Ofcourse any questions you have I'll be happy to answer